# addEventlistener, array, as linkage

Tags: actionscript-3

I have added 10 movieclips with the AS linkage `Box` in this function. I've named the different instances `layer1` to `layer10`

My question is, how can one add an eventlistener to, lets say, only `layer4`?

```
var NUM_BOXES:int = 10;
var BOX_SPACING:int = 1;

var _boxes:Array = [];

function Test()
{
    for (var i:int = 0; i < NUM_BOXES; i++)
    {
        var box:Box = new Box( i + 1 );
        box.y = (box.height + BOX_SPACING) * i;
        box.name= "layer" +( i + 1);
        box.buttonMode = true;
        box.addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onBoxPress );
        box.addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onBoxRelease );
        addChild( box );
        _boxes.push( box );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var NUM_BOXES:int = 10;
var BOX_SPACING:int = 1;

var _boxes:Array = [];
var number:int;

function Test()
{
    for (var i:int = 0; i < NUM_BOXES; i++)
    {
            number = i + 1;
            var box:Box = new Box(number);
            box.y = (box.height + BOX_SPACING) * i;
            box.name= "layer" +(number);
            box.buttonMode = true;

            if(number == 4)
            {
                box.addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onBoxPress );
                box.addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onBoxRelease );
            }


            addChild( box );
            _boxes.push( box );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on *bluebill1049*'s answer:

The `if(number == 4)` approach is not scalable, i.e. if you want a hundred layers to have listeners, you can not write an `if` statement for each layer. The simple solution would be:

```
var NUM_BOXES:int = 10;
var BOX_SPACING:int = 1;

var _boxes:Array = [];

//Any numbers in this array are assigned listeners
var layers_with_listeners:Array = [1, 4, 9]; 

function Test()
{
    for (var i:int = 0; i < NUM_BOXES; i++)
    {
        var box:Box = new Box( i + 1 );
        box.y = (box.height + BOX_SPACING) * i;
        box.name= "layer" +( i + 1);
        box.buttonMode = true;

        if(layers_with_listeners.indexOf(i+1) != -1) {     
            box.addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onBoxPress );
            box.addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onBoxRelease );
        }

        addChild( box );
        _boxes.push( box );
    }
}
```